# @Autowired vs @Autowired with Setter

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a spring boot app that I am using with the Web Plugin.

In one class I have:

```
package com.test.company
@Component
@RestController
public class CompanyService {

   @Autowired
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;
```

And in another class I have:

```
package com.test.company
@Component
@RestController
public class CustomerSignUpService {

   private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Autowired
   public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
          this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
   }
```

Both classes work but if I try to inject mongo into the `CusomterSignUpService` class like I did in the `CompanyService` class, the `env` is injected fine, but mongo doesn't inject and I get a null pointer exception if I try to use it.

Any thoughts? `Main` package is `com.test`.

Comment: Remove `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your `Controller` might need to look like (removed `static` from property):

```
package com.test.company
@Component
@RestController
public class CustomerSignUpService {

   @Autowired
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Autowired` both in the attribute and in the setter, but your attribute must be an instance variable, not a static one.

So do this and your code should run fine:

```
package com.test.company
@Component
@RestController
public class CustomerSignUpService {

   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Autowired
   public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
          this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
   }
```

Note that the `static` reserved word was taken from your attribute declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Remove static from the property and try it without it

```
package com.test.company
@Component
@RestController
public class CustomerSignUpService {

   @Autowired
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   ...
   ...
}
```